# Maximum Concentration of Benzene possible

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, concentration

A question for my PhysOrg course states:

> Assume you are performing a reaction in which benzene is a reagent. What is the maximum concentration of benzene possible? Hint: what facts do you need to know to determine concentration?

I understand concentration is amount per volume in mol/L, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I figured it out- just substitute mols for mass/MW and density  for volume and rearrange until you get density/MW

Comment: You mean divide 876g/l by 78 g/mol, which gives you 11.2 mol/l. Jup. Water, for comparison, is 55.4 mol/l.